# Non-void function potential lack of return

Tags: c++, coding-style

I wrote this piece of code to check if a node is a left or right child in a tree. However from a cleanliness perspective, I don't think it is properly implemented.

My issue is that returning a default like false if the parent pointer is null, is dangerous because false would mean it's a right child. However this function needs a return if I want it to compile without warnings. The empty throw is definitely ugly as a solution.

I have seen people use `assert(parent)` instead of `if`, but I don't think that's good either because the assert a debug feature.

In short, what are better ideas to implement this function?

```
bool isLeftChild() const {
    if(parent){
        if(this == (parent->left).get()){
            return true;
        }
        else if(this == (parent->right).get()){
            return false;
        }
    }
    else throw;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, `isLeftChild()` should not care if something does or does not exist (of course it still needs to perform checks to ensure that there is no nullptr dereferencing). It either returns `true` or `false`, but `false` should **not** mean that the node is the right child. It should just inform that it is **not the left child**.

Comment: `else throw;` is not good, you need to actually throw something, just `throw` is used to rethrow an exception that got caught. As for function itself, I think I you can make several different implementations of it with different behaviors and each of them can be helpful in some scenario.

Comment: Simply say in  your documentation  that if `parent` is null, you are in undefined behaviour teritory. It is up to the caller of the function to make sure that `parent` is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleanliness is ultimately a matter of opinion. What you're having trouble with is the question of what this function's contract is. That is, do you want it to define the behavior of this code if it is called on a node with a NULL parent?

If the answer is yes, then throwing is perfectly valid. Much like `vector::at` throws if the index is out of bounds.

```
bool isLeftChild() const
{
    if(!parent) throw ...;

    if(this == (parent->left).get()){
        return true;
    }
    else if(this == (parent->right).get()){
        return false;
    }
}
```

If the answer is no, then you shouldn't throw. This is how `vector::operator[]` works with an out-of-bounds index. In C++20, you would express this as a contract:

```
bool isLeftChild() const
    [[expects: parent != nullptr]]
{
    if(this == (parent->left).get()){
        return true;
    }
    else if(this == (parent->right).get()){
        return false;
    }
}
```

But this is conceptually an assert; you are saying that undefined behavior results if you call this function on a node with a NULL parent.

Which is "cleaner" is up to you and how you want your interface to behave. "Wide contracts" (where you throw on failure rather than invoke UB) are often seen as the "safer" alternative. This is primarily true in that you get an exception thrown from the place where things went wrong, rather than from other locations. But in this particular case, if `parent` is NULL, you'll immediately find out when you try to dereference it.

But even so, wide contracts are generally considered poor form in modern C++. Indeed, with contracts in C++20, the committee is looking into slowly removing the places in the standard library that throw `logic_error`s, turning them instead into contract violations (ie: UB).

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what you want. I would argue that a function called `isLeftChild()` should return `false` in case the node is not anyone's child, because if it's no one's child, it's definitely not a left child…

Concerning the use of `assert()`, you should ask yourself the question: is it necessary to guarantee well-defined behavior for a case where the function is incorrectly called? The point of `assert()` is to catch situations that should never occur in a correct program. Once you build your release version, these checks should not be necessary anymore, because the situations they check for can (should) never occur. Also, note that your `throw` expression without an argument will simply call `std::terminate()` unless there is an active exception being handled. I doubt that `isLeftChild()` is intended to be called exclusively only from inside `catch` blocks!? So for this `throw` to do what you most likely intended to do, you need to throw *something*, for example an `std::logic_error`.